# CURL PHP value_error.missing

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to call toonify API using  CURL/PHP, but i keep getting the error below :

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","image"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}
```

Here is my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

$params = array('name'=>'@alex.jpg;type=image/jpeg');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://toonify.p.rapidapi.com/v0/toonify');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: image/jpeg';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
$headers[] = 'X-Rapidapi-Host: toonify.p.rapidapi.com';
$headers[] = 'X-Rapidapi-Key: mey_key';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);


if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Any help please ?

Comment: What do the `toonify` api docs say regarding the required parameters you must send?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use: `array('name' => '@alex.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg');`? (saying this without any knowledge of the toonify API.)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius from their API here is the basic curl command :  curl \
    -F 'image=@/path/to/your/file.jpg' \
    -H 'api-key:82a92391-a234-4692-9b1f-8d7e6e642580' \
    https://api.deepai.org/api/toonify